# Groupby and get value in N-days in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe, representing daily stock values:

```
print(df)

date         ticker     price
19/04/22      AAPL      10
19/04/22      TSLA      15
20/04/22      TSLA      15
20/04/22      AAPL      10
(...)
```

For each date and ticker, I would like to retrieve the (future) **actual** price value, if present within the DataFrame, in N-days (with N = 30).

How can I achieve that using Pandas?

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the highest (future) price value? There could be multiple values

Comment: No, the actual future value present in the DataFrame

Comment: Please also show how the expected output would look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `merge`:

```
# convert date to timestamp
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%y')

# merge with shifted date
df.merge(df.assign(date=df['date']-pd.Timedelta('30D')),
         on=['date','ticker'], how='left', suffixes=['','_30D'])
```

Output:

```
        date ticker  price  price_30D
0 2022-04-19   AAPL     10        NaN
1 2022-04-19   TSLA     15        NaN
2 2022-04-20   TSLA     15        NaN
3 2022-04-20   AAPL     10       11.0
4 2022-05-20   AAPL     11        NaN
```

**Note**:

1. I added a `20/05/22` row to illustrate the shift.
2. Shifting by 4 weeks or 28 days would be better than 30 days, because shifting by 30 days might yield a lot of NaN values.